# How can I do the Angular 4 app automatically redirect to external url when the response is a 302 status code?

Tags: angular, http-status-code-302

This is the scenario:

I accessed the app. App try to perform a GET request to a sso.mydomain/authorization endpoint. This endpoint detect that a cookie is not present. So, sso.mydomain sends a 302 response, redirecting my app to another URL (sso.mydomain/login).

Here, the fail occurs. Browser doesn't redirect to sso.mydomain/login - Angular perform a GET to sso.mydomain/login, like an API endpoint.

I want that browser redirects to sso.mydomain/login. How can I do this? Why browser doesn't perform the redirection?

Comment: Angular navigates your app by utilizing its `Router` module. In your case, I would send a `false` boolean back from the call if it's a 302 response. Then on Angular side, check this boolean and if it's `false` then you can `navigate['your-url']`. 

If you're using `HttpClient` then you can implement `HttpInterceptor`. Read up: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

Comment: 302 redirect responses are caught by browsers before angular (or any application) ever gets a hold of it, you cannot do anything with this response.  If the issue is that the user is unauthorized you should use a 401 response code and let angular handle it's own redirect logic.

Comment: If the response is caught by browser before angular, why the browser itself doesn't redirect?

Comment: because the initial request was an ajax request, the ensuing "redirect" is also an ajax request... you CANNOT intercept a 302 from an angular context.  Find another way. a 401 is the correct response for an unauthorized user.

Comment: @bryan60 I do not want to intercept with the angular. I want to be redirected automatically by the browser. I want to go to an external URL. I know that 401 is the correct response for an unauthorized user, but the redirection allow to set a cookie to a domain knowed by both angular application. It's part of OAuth flow.

Comment: The browser is redirecting, as an ajax request, as per the expectation of browser behavior, as I've said a few times now, you need to find another way.